# java generics - The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?) in the type Comparable<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

So I want to do this:

```
public interface IFieldObject {
    public Comparable get();
}

public interface IFieldCondition {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject field, Comparable compare);
}

public class EqualTo implements IFieldCondition {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject field, Comparable compare) {
        return (field.get().compareTo(compare) == 0);       
    }    
}
```

but Eclipse gives me warnings:

> Type safety: The method compareTo(Object) belongs to the raw
>   type Comparable. References to generic
>   type Comparable should be
>   parameterized

So I turned this into:

```
public interface IFieldObject {
    public Comparable<?> get();
}

public interface IFieldCondition {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject field, Comparable<?> compare);
}

public class EqualTo implements IFieldCondition {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject field, Comparable<?> compare) {
        return (field.get().compareTo(compare) == 0);       
    }
}
```

which does not compile because of:

> The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?)
>   in the type Comparable
>   is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Comparable)

What's the right way to do that ? 
(without warnings following idiomatic Java >= 1.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
public interface IFieldObject {
    public<T> Comparable<T> get();
}

public interface IFieldCondition {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject field, Comparable<?> compare);
}

public class EqualTo implements IFieldCondition {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject field, Comparable<?> compare) {
        return (field.get().compareTo(compare) == 0);       
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good ! can you point me to a resource that explains the difference between "public Comparable<?> foo()" and "public <T> Comparable<T> foo()" ?

Comment: Check [Java generic methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Answer (score 4):

Currently you've no guarantee that the type returned by `field.get()` is really comparable with the type specified by the method. Ideally, make the whole thing generic, e.g.:

```
public interface IFieldObject<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public T get();
}

public interface IFieldCondition<T> {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject<T> field, Comparable<T> compare);
}

public class EqualTo<T> implements IFieldCondition<T> {
    public boolean apply(IFieldObject<T> field, Comparable<T> compare) {
        return (field.get().compareTo(compare) == 0);       
    }
}
```

You could no doubt make this more general using extra captures, but that's the starting point.

Comment: I wish i could have avoided extra specs on IFieldObject<T ...>. It looks like the "Old school" java version just "works" and it's more compact but I get the point. I really would have preferred a runtime error than all this typing around :)

Comment: One way I find convinient to read generic methods is: for all type T, get() returns a Comparable<T>.

Comment: to make it even better, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, to make it work for subclasses of comparable types