# Generic method determining if ArrayList is in order (Java)

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, comparable

I'm trying to write a method that determines if an ArrayList is in ascending order. The ArrayList type could be Integer, String etc. As a Java beginner, I've spent the last several hours getting my head around generics, comparable etc. and this is what I've got so far:

```
static boolean isOrdered(ArrayList<? extends Comparable<?>> a) {
    for(int i=0; i < a.size()-1; i++) {
        if (a.get(i).compareTo(a.get(i+1)) > 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I get the following compile error:

> The method compareTo(capture#11-of ?) in the type Comparable is not applicable for the arguments (capture#12-of ? extends Comparable

From what I gather from reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872251/java-generics-the-method-comparetocapture1-of-in-the-type-comparablecapt) I understand that it is because it's not sure if a comparison can be made. However I'm still not sure how to correct this.

I'm still quite new to Java (coming from Python). Would kindly appreciate any advice/insights. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the generics here.  The way to solve this is to tell the compiler that all the elements are of the same type, called `T`:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isOrdered(ArrayList<T> list)
  ...
}
```

This means that the whole list contains all elements of some type `T` that supports comparing values to other `T` values.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! I didn't realise I had to define the type after static; I tried that within the parentheses to no (useful) effect

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`